# Is there a way that I can add a string containing a LINQ where clause to a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
         switch (Settings.cvm)
         {
            case CVM.IncludeHidden:
                return new SelectedPhrases()
                {
                    ps = ps,
                    psNoa = psNoa
                };
            case CVM.ExcludeHidden:
                return new SelectedPhrases()
                {
                    ps = ps.Where(x => x.Hidden == false).ToList(),
                    psNoa = psNoa.Where(x => x.Hidden == false).ToList()
                };
            case CVM.Hidden:
                return new SelectedPhrases()
                {
                    ps = ps.Where(x => x.Hidden == true).ToList(),
                    psNoa = psNoa.Where(x => x.Hidden == true).ToList()
                };
            case CVM.Favorites:
                return new SelectedPhrases()
                {
                    ps = ps.Where(x => x.Favorite == true).ToList(),
                    psNoa = psNoa.Where(x => x.Favorite == true).ToList()
                };
            default:
                return null;

        }
```

Is there any way that rather than returning from inside the switch I could have the switch return me just the where clause for example:

```
x => x.Hidden == false
```

and then after the switch add that where clause to the variables ps and psNoa?

Comment: Use Dynamic LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delegates Func for the where clause. Then put the delegate in the Where() method.

```
void Main()
{
    var persons = new []
    {
        new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Alice", Active = true },
        new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Bob", Active = false },
        new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Charlie", Active = true },
    };

    Func<Person, bool> whereClause;

    var isActive = true; // change the value here
    if (isActive)
        whereClause = x => x.Active == true;
    else
        whereClause = x => x.Active == false;

    var query = persons.Where(whereClause);
    query.Dump();   
}

class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

**Result in LinqPad:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes indeed you can

in the switch just do

```
case zzz:
    ps = ps.Where(xxxxx).ToList();
    psnoa = psnoa.Where(yyyy).ToList();
    break;
....
```

then after the switch.

```
            return new SelectedPhrases()
            {
                ps.ToList(),
                psNoa.ToList()
            };
```

the point is you can build a pipeline of LINQ operations as you go along.
Note - it would be better to leave every thing as IEnuemrable rather than List. That would defer the evaluation until the end

Comment: Unfortunately, thanks to a previous question, the OP declared `ps` and `psNoa` as `List<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: so? List<T> is IEnumerable<T>

Comment: `List<T> x = (IEnumerable<T>)y;` (your first code snippet) doesn't compile

Comment: ah ok. FIxed, but IEnumerable everyhwere would be better obviuolsy